# Why is my json response transformed with a header and body?

Tags: json, pipeline, biztalk

I have a rest full service I call from BizTalk using a custom pipeline.

The request works fine,  but on the response the xml did not transform to canonical.

I used passthrough to get hold of the xml and got the following below:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
        xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://XXX.com.au/2022/11/Ros/Communication/SMSRequestResponse</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:a4fbf43a-8901-46e3-92ee-fb84af76d8fc</a:MessageID>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <ns0:SmsResponse xmlns:ns0="http://XXX.com.au/2022/10/Communication/Sms">
        <status>ENROUTE</status>
        <id>486440395</id>
        <destination>0167600123</destination>
        <error>
            <statusCode/>
            <statusText/>
            <errorCode>0</errorCode>
            <errorType/>
            <errorDescription/>
        </error>
    </ns0:SmsResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelop>
```

I was created the following schema based on the JSON received.

```
{
           "status": "ENROUTE",
           "id": 486414002,
           "destination": "0167600123",
           "error": {
                          "statusCode": null,
                          "statusText": null,
                          "errorCode": 0,
                          "errorType": null,
                          "errorDescription": null
           }
}
```

Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://XXX.com.au/2022/10/Communication/Sms" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://XXX.com.au/2022/10/Communication/Sms" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo is_envelope="no" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="SmsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Status" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Id" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Destination" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Error">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="StatusCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="StatusText" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="ErrorCode" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="ErrorType" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="ErrorDescription" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I have sent the AddMessageBodyForEmptyMessage to false.

Why is the envelope, header and body tags added to the xml?

Is there a way to get rid of them or must I copy the body to another schema and then transform that to the canonical?
I also tried to update the schema to the structure with envelope, header and body. But when I tried to validate an instance it still failed.

Comment: I am using BizTalk 2020 and it calling a .Net 6 REST service. The Receive pipeline is a custom pipeline using a JSON Decoder and XML disassembler.

Comment: I found it, the body and header info is added as part of the receive location on the other end, when subscribing using a file adaptor to the incoming message it is in the correct format.

Comment: Use the [Edit] link to add additional information to the question, rather than in the comments.  If you have solved it, then post it as an answer.